# Add extra explanatory layer onto PCA

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, pca, layer

I am trying to run a PCA on a dataframe which is accompanied by a metadata table. The PCA table is all normalized, scaled etc. the metadata, however, is not.

I want the PCA to not only cluster based on the dataframe but also the option to add one or multiple columns from the metadata table as explanatory variables as well. Again, these are not scaled and normalized with the main dataset. Also, I am not looking to color the plots with a certain data column, I'd want the column to be considered for the actual clustering.

I am aware that this sounds kinda vague, but I am having a hard time to find the exact words. After looking around for a little bit I found [demixed PCA](https://elifesciences.org/articles/10989) which seems to be very close to what I want to achieve. Sadly, there is no package in R to run it.

Any recommendations are welcome and thank you in advance.

Comment: You may have a look at package **vegan** where you can use `rda` for the PCA and then overlay additional explanation variables with `envfit`.  The package contains several plotting functions, so different colors are no problem.